# pass "html input value" to angular process

Tags: html, angular, input

I am stumped at this point. I have data that I'm collecting that I would like to use to be processed via the Angular component. While I have a value name in the HTML input statement, I need a way to pass that value through to the .ts process I will use it in. So far, all I get is "undefined".

```
app.component.html

<div>
  Common Name:
  <input name="commonName" value="">
  <p>
    <button (click)="assignName(commonName)">Submit</button>
    </p>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The process is here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  assignName (commonName: string) {
    console.log("value received: " + commonName);
  }

}
```

When I run it, I get the following in my console:

```
app.component.ts:11 value received: undefined
```

If I type in testing in the input, and hit submit, I would like to see the value received to be reported as it was typed ("testing")

[Snapshot of run window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70WdH.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Template Variable on the `input` and then you can use it's `value` property while calling the `assignName` method.

Something like this:

```
<div>
  Common Name:
  <input #commonName name="commonName" value="">
  <p>
    <button (click)="assignName(commonName.value)">Submit</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5rmmlq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thats it - Thank you!